# Is it possible to upload JSON data, generated by JS, as a file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, post

So I have a JavaScript that does some work on the **client side** and **generates about 1-3 MB of JSON data**. This chunk of data needs to be **uploaded to the server**. Right now I'm simply doing a normal **ajax post request**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/reports',        
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/jsonrequest',
    data: jsonData
})
```

On the server side I'm receiving the data (in Rails) like this:

```
def create
  request.body.rewind
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  ...
end
```

**I'm wondering if there is a better way**. Feels like posting 3 MB of data might cause trouble in some browsers, but file uploads generally work.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to upload 3 mb of data without actually sending all 3mb?  Otherwise, it makes little difference how you send the data.

Comment: No I'mm asking if there is a way to somehow emulate a  file upload. I don't know why but since I had problems when I wasn't using the contentType: 'application/jsonrequest' I wasn't sure if it was the right way to do it.

Comment: "application/jsonrequest" is not a valid Content-Type.  Perhaps you are looking for "application/json".

Comment: Well, according to [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html) it is.

Comment: That is a proposal.  It is not part of any accepted specification.